# Solr for Typo3: not searching in dynamic fields

Tags: solr, typo3

I'm using the Typo3 Solr Extension 2.8.3 and added some dynamic fields into the typoscripts definition.

So for example, there is a dynamic field defined for `plugin.tx_solr.index.queue.tx_news.author_stringS = author`
among the other typical definitons.

It seems that the dynamic fields are not put into the index automatically.

Is there a way to tell solr how to index dynamic fields too? - But using the typoscripts config ONLY. I don't like to touch the schema definition.

Answer (score 0):

Did you initialize the index queue after adding your dynamic field? If so, check in your Solr Admin if the field was added and if there is any content in it.

Adding fields without changing the schema definitely works out of the box.

**EDIT:**

Adding fields to the Solr index doesn't mean that they are used for the search query. You must include your dynamic field also to the query using TypoScript.

See the official documentation:

http://forge.typo3.org/projects/extension-solr/wiki/Tx_solrsearch#queryfields

Comment: yes, i've initialized the index queue. i've even tried after emtptying the index. using the solr admin interface the additional fields are displayed: eg. <str name="book_author_stringS">Christian Kreuzer</str> is in the resultset but when i search for "Christian" this result is not included

Comment: i've now put the additional entries into tx_solr.search.query.fields but still the same. 
may there be a problem because some tables don't have all fields? so e.g. in tx_foo there is an additionalField text_stringS but not in tx_bar. in query.fields text_stringS is added.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

That should do the trick :

```
plugin.tx_solr.search.query.queryFields = author_stringS^10.0
```

I suggest you use `author_textS` to make it more flexible in the search. *_stringS is exact and case sensitive.

If you set `queryFields` don't forget to add every other fields you want to be included in the search:

```
plugin.tx_solr.search.query.queryFields = content^40.0, title^5.0, keywords^2.0, tagsH1^5.0, tagsH2H3^3.0, tagsH4H5H6^2.0, tagsInline^1.0, description^4.0, author_textS^10.0
```